# Routing along existing road network using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-network-analysis

I just started learning QGIS and PyQGIS. I have one layer of a shapefile that contains a road network (image 1) and one layer of the CSV file (image 2) that contains several start and end points for certain roads within the road network.

How do I get the route from start to end points using the existing road network shapefile?

Unfortunately, those two layers come from different sources, so they don't share the same id or road name. I think the only way to connect those layers is by coordinating location.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: There is a module called « split lines at points ».

Answer (score 1):

But if you need to have distance from start to end, in reference to roads, you need to use a specific plugin for that: [LRS](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lrs/)
It does exactly what you need!